# Drupal 7 Taxonomy term with count

Tags: drupal, taxonomy

I tried the taxonomy menu module, but the main feature I need from it, the counter, does not work properly, so maybe there is some other way to achieve this.

My menu needs to look something like this:

Food(12)
-Fruits(8)
--Apple(3)
--Banana(5)
-Snacks(4)
--Biscuits(2)
--Chocolate(2)

So the top categories count the content of the subcategories, they have no content by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Views. Please try http://www.brightwebsitedesign.com/how-to-use-views-aggregator-to-create-taxonomy-term-count-block

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w22Utjm-chs